# After 48 hours, my validator request is still "Pending" (Deposited)

Tags: proof-of-stake, eth-2.0, beacon-chain, validators, medalla

I'm playing around with Ethereum 2.0 Proof of stake for my upcoming guide [Come fare staking con Ethereum 2.0](https://turbolab.it/criptovalute-bitcoin-ethereum-litecoin-4904/coma-fare-staking-ethereum-2.0-guida-definitiva-guadagnare-interessi-video-3050) (italian only, sorry). I setup Go Ethereum and Nimbus, generated the required keys via eth2.0-deposit-cli and deposited 32 fake ETH (from Goerli) via Medalla Launchpad.

But [when I check mystatus](https://beaconcha.in/validator/a03ac241f2be0852b3cefc9581f796adf5ebd19775e83e2b12ebe5643b9d488aaa4016a31c03d4a7e930d76e0adf11b4#overview) I see:

> Deposited - An ETH1 deposit has been made, it will take around 8 hours until your deposit is processed by the beacon chain. Check out the deposits tab for more details

The deposit was made over two days ago (more than 48h).

So.... did I miss something or should I just wait? Is it possible to get an ETA somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost 3 days, the status of my validator changed from `Deposited` to `Pending`. So, yeah, I did everything alright and I just had to wait (a lot) longer than the expected 8 hours.

Now, as expected, I must wait for the actual activation. The site currently reports `Estimated Activation: in 12d`.

Answer (score 1):

After a deposit was processed, your validator still needs to be activated. The deposit takes on average 8 hours, but activation takes multiple days, depending on the current queue and whether the network has finality. Only with finality new validators can be activated, but [Medalla hasn't finalised in quite a while](https://beaconcha.in/epochs). You will need to wait for Medalla to reach finalisation again, and then for the queue of new validators to be processed.

Comment: thanks, I understood that the new validator must be activated and that is a second, distinct phase. What I don't understand is why, after 48+ hours, the deposit is not even being "processed" yet when it should require 8 hours.